# Comparing multi-dimensional lists in R

Tags: r, vectorization

I have the following two lists:

```
First list:
[[1]]
[1] "ab" "iew"  "rer" "fdd"     
[[2]]
[1] "ff" "de 
[[3]]
[1] "cc"

Second list:
[[1]]
[1] "iew" "vfr" 
[[2]]
[1] "ff" "cdc"
[[3]]
[1] "vf" "cde"
```

My goal is to compare these two multi-dimensional lists, so that the result would be:

```
[[1]]
[1] FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE 
[[2]]
[1] TRUE FALSE
[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

What is the best vectorized way to preform this intersect() function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `mapply`

```
> mapply("%in%", Firt.list, Second.list)
[[1]]
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1]  TRUE FALSE

[[3]]
[1] FALSE
```

Where `First.list` and `Second.list` are:

```
Firt.list <- list(c("ab", "iew",  "rer", "fdd" ), c("ff", "de"), c("cc"))
Second.list <- list(c("iew", "vfr"), c("ff", "cdc"), c("vf", "cde"))
```

If you want to know which values are the  `intersect`s of the lists, then try this

```
> mapply("intersect", Firt.list, Second.list)
[[1]]
[1] "iew"

[[2]]
[1] "ff"

[[3]]
character(0)
```